# WPF: calendar control date in bold

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

I retrieve some dates from my database and i want show that dates in my calendar control in c# wpf using a bold style.

How can i do this only from code behind? Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Calendar: Boldface specified dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505162/wpf-calendar-boldface-specified-dates)

Comment: If possibile i want use only code behind